# Non-metaphoric term for "selling snake oil"

Tags: verbs, idioms, vocabulary

Is there a single verb that denotes promoting or proselytizing an idea to a victim who stands to lose in some way if fallen prey to it? Other than "politics"...

An idiomatic or metaphoric expression would be "selling snake oil". But is there a single verb that means the same?

Comment: That isn't what a snake-oil salesman does. Which do you want, a substitute for selling snake-oil, or something akin to proselytizing?

Answer (score 7):

> ## Scam
>
> a fraudulent or deceptive act or operation

alternatively

> ## Swindle
>
> to obtain money or property by fraud or deceit

Comment: Or fraud / defraud.